# Find minimum in array of arrays js

Tags: javascript

I have an array of arrays, each one of them consists of two values - timestamp and price.

```
[
  [1147651200000, 376.2],
  [1147737600000, 350],
  [1147824000000, 374.5]
]
```

I need to find date and time in which price was the **lowest** among all points. 
What function should I use, pls help.

EDIT:

Thanks everyone! I took tests to to see which function is fastest.
Here is how I did it (example with .sort, others are same)

```
console.time('cycle');
var k = 0;
while (k<10000) {
var input = [
  [1147651200000, 376.2],
  [1147737600000, 350],
  [1147824000000, 374.5]
];

var output = input.sort(function(a,b){
  return a[1] > b[1];
})[0];
k++;
}
console.log(output);
console.timeEnd('cycle'); //36 ms

.map //67 ms
minimum in cycle // 108 ms
```

Comment: Use `.sort` with a custom callback to sort by the price value, then get the first element of the resulting array. This will be the one with the lowest price.

Comment: can you show an example pls?

Comment: The underscore library has a min function that can achieve this easily, `var min = _.min( input_array, function(n){ return n[1]; });`

Comment: Nope. That's not what StackOverflow is for :p Search around, give it a try, and if you have problems then come back with some code ;)

Comment: ok, i think i got it, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just try with:

```
var input = [
  [1147651200000, 376.2],
  [1147737600000, 350],
  [1147824000000, 374.5]
];

var output = input.sort(function(a,b){
  return a[1] > b[1];
})[0];
```

Output:

```
[1147737600000, 350]
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with this solution, just want to point out in case you have a huge amount of elements. You can find the lowest item in `O(n)` other than quick-sort using `O(n log n)`.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek, I do have huge amount of elements. But i did'n get you answer. Can you clarify pls what function should look like?

Comment: @ProstoTrader: I've posted an O(N) answer.

Comment: @ProstoTrader: As RichieHindle pointed out, there are a few `O(n)` solutions below. So I don't need to post an answer that they already have done.

Comment: .sort is fastest among .map and cycle o(n)

Comment: @ProstoTrader `.sort()` is not faster. Again it's `O(n)` vs `O(n log n)`, you are only testing for a 3 element array. With a few thousand elements you will see that `O(n)` is faster. For example `n = 3` : `n log n = 1.431` vs `n = 3`. But `n = 1000` : `n log n = 3000` vs `n = 1000`. These are not opinions.

Answer (score 2):

Sorting the array is O(N logN) - if performance with large arrays might be an issue, here's an O(N) solution:

```
var min = a[0];
for (var i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (a[i][1] < min[1]) {
        min = a[i];
    }
}

// min is now [1147737600000, 350]
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the numbers from the array into a new array, use Math.min to get the lowest, and backtrack to get the timestamp.

```
var arr = [
  [1147651200000, 376.2],
  [1147737600000, 350],
  [1147824000000, 374.5]
] 

var numbs     = arr.map(function(x) { return x[1]||0 });
var timestamp = arr[numbs.indexOf(Math.min.apply( Math, numbs ))][0];
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/teeB6/1/)

Comment: @ProstoTrader - Array.sort would by far be the slowest way to do this, if you can prove otherwise, show us.

Comment: @adeneo: Thanks for putting together those tests!  You should post the reverse-for example as an answer.

Comment: @adeneo, look at the edit, it shows, how I did tests. I moght be wrong but minimum time has sort.

Comment: @ProstoTrader: You timed how long it took to find the minimum of three items, ten thousand times.  In your comment you said "I do have huge amount of elements."  It would make more sense to time how long it takes with a huge amount of elements, not how long it takes with three.  adeneo's tests time it with a thousand elements.

Comment: OK I got it. I think you are right, I've just tried to make quick tests in console.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
var min = arr[0][1];
var timestamp = 0;
for(i in arr) {
    if(arr[i][1] <= min ) {
        min = arr[i][1];
        timestamp = arr[i][0];
    }
}
```